# What argument should I be passing to "root" when importing a tkinter file?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-module, katalon-recorder

This is likely a very basic question, but I am trying to code something with very little knowledge of Python at the moment.

I am writing a script that will open a GUI (designed in PAGE, which works with tkinter) for a user to enter several inputs. When they click submit, the code stores the values from their inputs as variables and destroys the GUI window. At this point it begins running a Selenium script (created in the Katalon IDE) to control a browser window and begin using the information in the inputs to populate fields in a web form.

My tkinter files consist of one main file for the GUI that inputs a support file that defines what happens when the button is pressed. Right now I am importing the the main GUI tkinter file to the Selenium script file and then at the bottom of the file, running this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
SNinput.create_New_Toplevel(root)
unittest.main()
```

I am passing root because my primary tkinter file (SNinput.py) contains this function:

```
def create_New_Toplevel(root, *args, **kwargs):
'''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
global w, w_win, rt
rt = root
w = Toplevel (root)
top = New_Toplevel (w)
SNinput_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
return (w, top)
```

When I run the Selenium file, I get a TypeError that it's missing a positional argument: 'root'. What am I missing? What should I be passing to that function?

Alternately, should I have this process reversed, since I want to launch the GUI first and only then run the Selenium script? In other words, import the Selenium script (servicenow.py) into SNinput.py and then find a way to run that file when I click the submit button? The reason I didn't do this is I don't see a way to pass those variables down to the called function.

EDIT:
I have tried passing in several variations on 'tkinter' in place of root within my servicenow.py file but each time I get the error that the name is not defined.

At the top of my servicenow.py, I import the GUI module:

```
import SNinput
```

In the GUI module SNinput.py, the the initial imports and function definiations are as follows:

```
import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import SNinput_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    top = New_Toplevel (root)
    SNinput_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_New_Toplevel(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    top = New_Toplevel (w)
    SNinput_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_New_Toplevel():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None
```

Answer (score 1):

When written in modular manner it doesn't really matter which script drives the other. I personally prefer to make the GUI import other scripts.

If we were to assume that the first code snippet is indented correctly, and that it is somewhat the entire script, then the error is only natural because `root` by itself has no meaning. One must first assign an object to it for it to have a meaning.

By looking at your `create_New_Toplevel`, it looks like you should be passing an instance of `tkinter.Tk` class. Replace 'main' with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import tkinter # replace with Tkinter if python 2.x
    SNinput.create_New_Toplevel(tkinter.Tk())
unittest.main()
```

Comment: When passing tkinter.Tk() I get the error "name 'tkinter' is not defined". I've tried a few variations on that but am getting the same thing every time. Also, If I were to have the GUI module the Selenium module (servicenow.py), how would I pass my variables down to it?

Comment: @Mknerr What version of python do you have? Did you skip the import line?

Comment: Python 3.6.4. At the top of the servicenow.py file I have "import SNinput" which is the other module that runs the GUI. In that module there is:  import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import SNinput_support

Comment: I've updated the information in the initial post. I am still getting name not defined errors regardless of what I pass in place of root. @Nae

Comment: @Mknerr Have you tried `Tk()` by itself? As in `SNinput.create_New_Toplevel(Tk())`.

Comment: I just tried that, but it's still giving me a NameError :/ @Nae

Comment: File "servicenow.py", line 124, in <module>   SNinput.create_New_Toplevel(ttk())   NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined    @Nae

Comment: I grabbed the wrong line -- I tried ttk immediately after that because in the other file there is an "import tkinter.tk as ttk". I did however also get an error when I used Tk(). @Nae

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167193/discussion-between-nae-and-mknerr).